# Extract APK including data to enable SSL proxying

Tags: android, apk, charles-proxy

I am trying to gain access to an API from an Android application, so I can extract the GET request and use it on my PC instead. I have verified that this is indeed possible, however, I have one problem: Their Firebase integration gives me a 403.

The app works like this:

1. Open app
2. Enter your address and select it from a list
3. Press "Add address"
4. App sends a POST request to Firebase (probably registrering a session or something)
5. App succeeds and returns to a "view" page, that contains the info I want to extract

I've extracted the app using `adb pull /data/app/....apk` and then used [AddSecurityExceptionAndroid](https://github.com/levyitay/AddSecurityExceptionAndroid) to enable debugging via Charles Proxy and so on, from my computer. Once I've built a new APK, simply install it with `adb install application.apk`.

Once I launch the newly installed app, I am once again greeted with the same "Enter your address" popup, like it completely forgot I already entered it once. Is there a way to bypass this, so the APK I extract already has this data? Or keep it on the device for future use, so when I install my patched APK, it's already "signed in"?

The problem is, if I only enable SSL proxying for `*.apiwebsite.com` and let my phone handle everything else, it works great until I need to send a POST request to `firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com`, where my phone just hangs and eventually the app crashes. It happens right after I press the `Add address` button, after searching for my address and selecting the correct one.

So I either need to find a way to make it not fail with Firebase, or somehow extract the APK, so I can "sign in" beforehand, pull the APK, patch the APK, and then install the APK, so the app already knows I am "signed in".

The Firebase error is:

> Requests from this Android client application correct.url.here are blocked

Answer (score 0):

Okay,  I managed to get something working. First I installed Genymotion, then I booted up a rooted Android 8.0 virtual machine, to which I then installed the app I needed to "debug" and HttpCanary.

Logged every TLS/SSL request perfectly and I was able to retrieve the URL for the API I needed.